# protractor drag and drop is not working on chrome

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I having an issue with protractor v~5.3.0 . I was trying to drag and drop an element from this site : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

at the bottom, there are four square that we can drag and drop. but through protractor, I can only drag the element but could not drop it. here is the code that I wrote. please let me know what wrong have I done. thanks in advance.

```
describe('germi App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach(() => {
    page = new AppPage();

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
  });

  it('should  drag and drop with JavaScript', async () => {
    await page.navigate2();
    const element1 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="columns-full"]/div[1]'));
    const element2 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="columns-full"]/div[2]'));
    browser.sleep(10000);

    /* browser
        .actions()
        .dragAndDrop(element1, element2)
        .perform();
    browser.sleep(5000); */

    browser.actions().
      mouseDown(element1).
      mouseMove(element2).
      mouseUp().
      perform();

    browser.sleep(5000);
  });
});
```

in case you want to check my navigate2 func .

```
navigate2() {
           return browser.get("https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/");
         }
```

Comment: There is an issue with drag and drop on protractor in HTML 5 web sites.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

And finally I was able to solve it using **browser.driver**.

It works better on AngularJS apps that take time to sync. browser.driver is more reliable in many cases.

```
  driver = browser.driver

  driver.actions().
  dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
  perform()
```

Hope this will be helpful to you!

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work. the code you gave work exactly same as before. it could drag the element but not let it drop to element2. :(  @Dilushika

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop functionality for HTML5 elements are not supported by current webdrivers.  You'll have to trigger the dragenter, dragover and drop events with some JavaScript.

**Solution:**

1. Download [drag_and_drop_helper.js](https://gist.github.com/rcorreia/2362544#file-drag_and_drop_helper-js) and save it in your machine.
2. Inside your test you can peform drag option using,

   ```
   var fs = require("fs");
   var dnd_js = fs.readFileSync(path/to/drag_and_drop_helper.js);
   driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");
   driver.executeScript(dnd_js+"$('#column-a').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '#column-b'});")
   ```

Refer http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop for additional information. Hope this might help you!

Comment: what is #column-a and #column-b here. How to pass source and destination webelement ??

Comment: When using your code on the sample site it works. But when i used it for my project site, it is giving below error.                                                            
Failed: javascript error: jQuery is not defined
      (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```
await page.navigate2();
const element1 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="columns-full"]/div[1]'));
const element2 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="columns-full"]/div[2]'));
browser.sleep(10000);

browser
    .actions()
    .dragAndDrop(await  element1.getWebElement(), await element2.getWebElement())
    .perform();
browser.sleep(5000);
```

I have made the change is this line because **dragAndDrop() method takes webElement as an input parameter.**

> .dragAndDrop(await  element1.getWebElement(), await element2.getWebElement())